# Is it more efficient to use nested queries?

Tags: query

I am trying to optimise/improve my codes to avoid limits especially for batches, starting on SOQL. I have this query string to get all accounts with closed won opportunities only:

```
query = 'Select Name, (Select Name, IsWon, IsClosed from Opportunities where IsWon = true and IsClosed = true) From Account';
```

which will then be executed by `Database.getQueryLocator(query);`

I am not sure if I'm doing this right though, but is this enough or is there anything more efficient to apply?

Comment: the alternative query is `select name,iswon, isclosed, account.name from Opportunity where isWon = true and isClosed = true order by account.name` - you could do execute anonymous and compare times

Comment: @cropredy The most efficient way is `select id from account where id in (select accountid from opportunity where iswon = true)`, actually.

Comment: @Mae remember to accept the answer if it proved useful, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your batch start method, do *not* use sub-queries. This will specifically invoke special behavior that increases the time used in the start method, and because sub-queries can use cursors, can result in sporadic errors otherwise. You can, however, use sub-queries in *filters* to make them more efficient. Either way, do your subqueries in the execute method.

Example:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
  return Database.getQueryLocator([
    Select Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN 
      (Select AccountId 
       FROM Opportunity 
       where IsWon = true and IsClosed = true)
  ]);
}
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Account[] scope) {
  Account[] records = [SELECT Name, 
    (SELECT ... FROM Opportunities WHERE ...) 
     FROM Account WHERE Id = :scope];
  ...
}
```

This design minimizes the start time's loading time, *and* guarantees that you have fresh data at the moment of execution.

---

Also, note specifically that your query queries *every account in the database*, while the example above will specifically return precisely "all accounts with closed won opportunities only."